# Visual Studio vsix package for custom command, similar to "Go To Definition" (F12)

Tags: visual-studio, roslyn, vsix, roslyn-code-analysis

My company wants a custom command in Visual Studio that would behave rather like the *Go To Definition* (F12) feature (from context menu in code editor window), in order to navigate to a specific implementation of a method inside the solution.

So I created a VSIX package from a sample on git hub and added a custom command item, and tweak the .vsct so it shows my new *Navigation* item in the context menu along with the other items (*'Quick Actions and Refactorings'*, *'Copy'*, *'Paste'*, etc.). This part is ok.

**Question 1** : In the call back of the command how can I retrieve the syntax and symbol classes from the piece of code that is under the carret of the code editor window ? `object sender` and `EventArgs e` parameters looks inacurate for my needs.  :/

**Question 2** : Using code analysis and compiler API features, how would I analyse semantics and then jumps to the right file and and class through the solution ? Are there any samples of code analyse with "jump to" functionality ?

Any tutorials, samples or recommandations are very welcome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Call the [`GetOpenDocumentInCurrentContextWithChanges()` extension method](http://source.roslyn.io/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.EditorFeatures.Text/Extensions.cs,82bf34180667ee95) (in Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.EditorFeatures.Text.dll) on an `ITextSnapshot` to get a Roslyn `Document`.

You can then use normal Roslyn APIs to get the semantic model, resolve symbols, examine the syntax tree, etc.

[Example](https://github.com/SLaks/Ref12/blob/master/Ref12.Roslyn/Services/RoslynSymbolResolver.cs)

Comment: @AntoineMeltzheim: That's a general VS extensibility question (it has nothing to do with Roslyn).  It depends on how you're registering your commands / associating with an editor.

Comment: For example, look at https://github.com/madskristensen/WebEssentials2015/blob/9a9eaa4455f9b146981252d7b03e45db3adf34ce/EditorExtensions/Shared/Helpers/ProjectHelpers.cs#L249

Comment: Finally I managed to get TextSnapshot, but I got an error that stops VS when the extension method GetOpenDocumentInCurrentContextWithChanges() is referenced in code : 

Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Workspaces' Version 2.3.0.0. 

I'm currently targeting version 2.3.1 of Roslyn and related assemblies, I tried 2.3.0 and same error. When I comment extension method I have no error.

Comment: Sounds like you're referencing a newer build of Roslyn than your VS.  Either upgrade VS or downgrade Roslyn to match your VS service pack.  You can see VS' version of Roslyn in Debug, Modules.

Comment: Down graded all Roslyn set to version 2.0.0, and it works, I can reach semantic model and symbol under the caret. Thanks for your very valuable help !